# Make do not rebuild a undo-checkouted file under clearcase

Tags: makefile, clearcase

I discovered a quite annoying issue with ClearCase and make. Make check if any of a target's dependencies is more recent than the target itself and this is is the way make should work.

If I undo-checkout a file on ClearCase. It's modification date will be older than the *checkouted* file. Thus make won't rebuild this file.

How can I solve this issue?

I see two possible solutions:

1. Tell ClearCase to update the modification date to when the undo-checkout was done.
2. Tell make to check if the modification date of the dependencies has changed (not to compare it to the target's modification date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a [ClearCase Explorer option](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_prefs_ccexplorer_details.htm?lang=en) (also [valid for ClearTeam 8.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_prefs_ccexplorer_details.htm?lang=en)) like "Preserve file modification time" (on add to source control or on checkout) would change anything.

It may have an influence on the timestamp when diong an undo-checkout.

Comment: Good, it was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks VonC!

Comment: @coin I have been there since 2008 (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309), every single day. And I always monitor the ClearCase tag (amongst others): http://stackoverflow.com/tags/clearcase/topusers